# Authenticate with the credentials provided

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to pull the ACC Issues from Postman to Powerbi, but it says we couldn't authenticate the credentials provided.
Can someone helpme with the error
[image]

To pull the Acc Issues in to Powerbi from Postman